# How to download file with MVC4/Razor having password protection

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

There is a link inside controller function through which a file is downloaded the only issue is that the link has password authentication on it ,what would be the appropriate method to perform the authentication and make the link downloadable after authenticating username and password.
Here is my controller function:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult ImportData()
{
    System.IO.DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/TempData/DataFile"));
    foreach (FileInfo csvfile in di.GetFiles())
    {
        csvfile.Delete();
    }

    MyWebClient webClient = new MyWebClient();

    webClient.DownloadFile("http://gis.abc.org.pk/report.php", Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/TempData/DataFile/Data.csv"));

    using (ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext())
    {
        db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SP_BulkInsertData");
        db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SP_InsertData");
        db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SP_VillageLevelDataCreation");
    }

    // return View();
    return RedirectToAction("ImportSendMail");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what is `MyWebClient` that you are using but you can simply use .Net `WebClient` and set credentials. Below is the sample code.

```
using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
{
    webClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password); //set username and password here
    webClient.DownloadFile("http://gis.abc.org.pk/report.php", Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/TempData/DataFile/Data.csv"));
}
```

Comment: it is giving the following error. Bulk load: An unexpected end of file was encountered in the data file.
Cannot obtain the required interface ("IID_IColumnsInfo") from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".

Comment: @SadiaRashid That's another error and it is not from the code download file code. Please check where exactly you get this error.

Comment: i m getting this error in bulk insert .The could not be opened. Operating system error code 80(The file exists.).According to my understanding and after searching this error is coming because the file has password authentication on it.

Comment: after searching on stack-overflow this error is coming because of the permission issues.

Comment: @SadiaRashid That's not related to your original question. Please ask a new question with specific details.

Comment: This error has appeared after trying the solution you have provided in reference to my question.

Comment: @SadiaRashid Bulk insert exception is related to database operation which you are doing somewhere else down the code. The solution I provided is only for downloading the file. Please provide the complete stack trace of the exception.

Comment: it is not downloading the file properly that is why i am having error in my stored procedure

Comment: I asked for the complete exception stack trace and the exact line where you are getting the error, which you failed to provide.

Comment: After using this method the file gets downloaded but it contains some javascript code for authentication of the login page. but don't contains the relevant data in the file could u tell what it means?

Comment: It is downloading a file that has html and javascript of the index page.its not logging into the site and not downloading the relevant csv file

Comment: @SadiaRashid Please provide the complete URL of the download link

Comment: tried this method as well with same results : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48185125/using-httpwebrequest-to-download-file-from-server

Comment: @SadiaRashid Well the web request that we are doing will work if the URL is capable of taking the credentials. May be I have to sit and check with you on this.

Comment: how can u help me in this?

Comment: @SadiaRashid May be through TeamViewer

Comment: come on linkedin

Comment: @SadiaRashid Let's catch up at 8:30 PM (GMT + 5.30)